# Showing a route between two points with multiple waypoints Android Here Map Lite Edition

Tags: java, android, kotlin, here-api, here-maps-rest

We are converting Android Project Here Map Android **Starter SDK** to **Lite Edition**. I want to display the multiple waypoints on route.

For Starter SDK we are using the **RoutePlan** for plotting the multiple waypoints. but in Lite Edition i am unable to find the RoutePlan. For more information find the below Android **Starter SDK** Code snippets:

```
    val routePlan = RoutePlan()
    val routeOptions = RouteOptions()
    routeOptions.transportMode = RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR
    routeOptions.routeType = RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST

    routePlan.routeOptions = routeOptions

   for (routeLatLang in tripRouteData) { 
                try {
                    routePlan.addWaypoint(GeoCoordinate(lat.toDouble(), longg.toDouble()))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
    }

    val error = routeManager.calculateRoute(routePlan, routeManagerListener)
    if (error != RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
        Toast.makeText(activity,
                "Route calculation failed with: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
    }
```

Also find the below code snippets of **Lite Edition** SDK :

```
    val waypoint1 = Waypoint(latitude1,longitude1)
    val waypoint2 = Waypoint(latitude2,longitude2)
    val waypoints = java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList(Waypoint(startGeoCoordinates),
            waypoint1, waypoint2, Waypoint(destinationGeoCoordinates)))
```

So, How we can plot the multiple waypoints on Here Map **Lite Edition**, Also what is limit of maximum waypoints to plot on route.

Answer (score 2):

It's a different SDK. Having a look at the [feature list](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/dev_guide/index.html#feature-list), you'll find that directions are supported. Thus you'll have to look at the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#directions) to figure out how it works.

Eventually you'll have to do something like:

```
routingEngine.calculateRoute(
        waypoints,
        new CarOptions(),
        new CalculateRouteCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRouteCalculated(@Nullable RoutingError routingError, @Nullable List<Route> routes) {
                if (routingError == null) {
                    Route route = routes.get(0);
                    showRouteDetails(route);
                    showRouteOnMap(route);
                } else {
                    showDialog("Error while calculating a route:", routingError.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The new SDK 4.x (Lite) has some different concepts and features than classic Starter SDK, so it's not a full drop in replacement.

For routing, things are quite similar, you can check out the github example for exactly your case here:

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/android/Routing/app/src/main/java/com/here/routing/RoutingExample.java

In a short:

RouteEngine still exists, but within the calculateRoute method you pass in a list of waypoints (first one is start, last one is end, everything in between are stopover or pass-through waypoints).

See : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/api_reference/com/here/sdk/routing/RoutingEngine.html#calculateRoute-java.util.List-com.here.sdk.routing.CarOptions-com.here.sdk.routing.CalculateRouteCallback-